# Finding an associated function among numbers

Tags: math

We have a set of 3 numbers and a number which is function output of these numbers.
For example:

```
2, 4, 9 = 88
3, 7, 8 = 76
4, 9, 6 = 55
```

Now the function is for example

```
( last digit X 10 ) - (second digit - first digit)
```

Thus
5, 8, 2 = 17

But we have to find out this formula by trial and error method.
Is there any mathematical technique, tool or any program to find out the function associated among the numbers?

Comment: The technique behind this is simply brute forcing.

Comment: You could define a set of allowed operations (add, subtract, divide, multiply) and apply them to the 3 numbers (n1, n2, n3) in various combinations. Then check if the result-value (r) is the one given.

If the acceptance criteria is really that badly defined, just use the formula: n1*0 + n2 * 0 + n3*0 + r. It always fits.

Comment: That's simply just solving a system of three linear equations...
Just write it as `2x + 4y + 9z = 88, 3x + 7y + 8z = 76, 4x + 9y + 6z = 55` and just use one of the normal mathematical methods of [solving a system of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system)

Comment: As @Alderath implies, if the number of variables equals the number of results you are given (3 in your example), you can almost always get an answer using linear equations. Do you know that will always be the case? Rarely you will get a singular matrix from the variables and there will be no linear solution. Do you know that will never happen? Without more restrictions, there are infinitely many ways to solve your question.